# How to print top level directories

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I want to only print the top level folders in my s3 bucket, how can i go about doing that?

```
client = boto3.client('s3', region_name='us-west-2')
paginator = client.get_paginator('list_objects')
page_iterator = paginator.paginate(Bucket='my-bucket')

for page in page_iterator:
    print(page['Contents'])
```

Here is what i have above,

but let say my folder structure is as so

```
folder1/folder/file
folder2/folder/file
folder2/folder/file2
folder3/file
```

How can i make it so only the top level folder name prints? So it looks like this below:

```
folder1
folder2
folder2
folder3
```

I am also using paginate because i have thousands. otherwise doing a list_objects will only print 1000.

Thanks!

Comment: To iterate over 1000, use StartAfter (on subsequent calls).

Comment: There are no folders in an S3 bucket, just a big flat list of objects. You can put slashes in the names of those objects, but that doesn't create folders. S3 _does_ have `prefix` and `delimiter` arguments for convenience, that let you sort of fake having folders, but that only goes so far—you can't "walk the tree" hierarchically, because there is no tree, just a flat list.

Comment: I figured it out `import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('edsu-test-bucket')
result = bucket.meta.client.list_objects(Bucket=bucket.name,
                                         Delimiter='/')
for o in result.get('CommonPrefixes'):
    print(o.get('Prefix'))`